# how is possible to use Google bearer token to authorize Google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

Is it possible to use bearer token from [Google API Client Javascript Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) to authorize Google cloud storage bucket without requesting https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage scope from user. The bucket has read and write access to all Google account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If the data is scoped to AllUsers, you could make the request anonymously, but you can't make requests to Google Cloud Storage on behalf of a user who hasn't granted you READ scope or better.

One possible alternative, depending on your use case: if the user happens to be signed in to their Google account, you could let them access the object directly using Cookie Authentication, for example by having them request the object via the URL pattern `https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucket/object`.

Comment: I see. I tried programatic access using Cookie Authentication, but it doesn't work. The resource URI is redirected to a random URI, which does not allow hidden iframe. Did I miss something?